# Like Time-To-Event analysis, but looking at the timing of events that do or do not happen on a binary outcome

Tags: regression, survival-analysis

I have  a problem where every observation has a binary outcome that occurs at the end of a fixed period, and the predictor variables describe a few types of event that either happen on some day within that period or do not happen at all. For example:

| Outcome | Days Until First Phone Call | Days Unit Second Phone Call |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TRUE | 3 | 14 |
| FALSE | 25 | 63 |
| FALSE | 16 | NA |

Of course I can convert the predictor columns to binary and use logistic regression to see if the events occurring at all has a relationship with the outcome. Is there technique to model the effect of the timing of the events as well? This seems like a subset of survival analysis, but so far my research has not uncovered a technique that is well defined and fits this problem.

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. I don't have a real answer but the first thing I would do with this is try to plot this data in a few different ways in order to visualize how the distributions differ for TRUE and FALSE. The simple option is to do the histogram of each individual feature in the two cases true/false. Another idea is a scatter plot with the two dimensions as the values of the features and using different colours for true/false.